# ¿Existen casos de reputación de +5 ó de -5 para respuestas?

Tags: soporte, reputación

Tengo dudas con respecto a un caso extraño que surgió ayer:

Un usuario planteó en días pasados varias preguntas, yo di respuesta a dos de esas preguntas (si mal no recuerdo, en al menos una de ellas o en las dos mi respuesta fue marcada como aceptada).

Luego otro usuario respondió a las preguntas de ese OP, en un caso copiando exactamente mi respuesta y en otro caso copiando exactamente la respuesta de otro usuario. En ambos casos el OP marcó como aceptada la respuesta que ese otro usuario había plagiado literalmente de otras respuestas ya dadas.

El caso es que, como muestra la imagen, en mi reputación aparece un `+5` en mi respuesta a una de esas preguntas y un `-5` en la otra respuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo a qué se debe ese `+5` y ese `-5`. Tenía entendido que **para respuestas** la reputación era:

- `+10` : voto a favor
- `+15` : respuesta aceptada
- `-2`  : voto en contra

¿Qué significan entonces ese `+5` y ese `-5`?

Comment: De hecho si miras en tu pestaña de reputación se ve el desglose: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano?tab=reputation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esas puntuaciones curiosas que has detectado tienen su origen en un par de usuarios (o el mismo con dos cuentas) que ayer se detectaron, uno copiando respuestas previamente aceptadas, y el otro que era el OP quitando la aceptación a las respuestas previamente aceptadas y aceptando la del otro usuario.

Por ejemplo, en uno de los casos que muestras, tu respuesta recibió 2 votos positivos (+20) y posteriormente se retiró como la respuesta aceptada (-15). Eso da como resultado un saldo positivo de reputación de +5. El otro caso es similar.

<sub>(Espero que se entienda el trabalenguas que he soltado)</sub>

Comment: Ya ya, tiene sentido lo que dices. O sea, en el `+5` y en el `-5` lo que me está mostrando digamos es **un resumen del día**. En el caso del `-5`, sería: un voto a favor `+10` y el OP la desmarcó como respuesta aceptada `-15`, quedando la respuesta en `-5`. Es que es un caso rarísimo y no había pensando que se trata en realidad de un cálculo global de lo que pasó en ese día con la respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Efectivamente. Si te fijas la reputación en esa pestaña se ve **por dia**, y por eso lo que has detectado

Comment: Sí, no caí en la cuenta de ello. Gracias y ¡enhorabuena! por la elección como moderador. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano, con vuestra ayuda trataremos de mejorar en lo posible el sitio :)